# How can I programmatically have multiple div elements in 1 introjs step

Tags: intro.js

From what I can tell, there's a way of setting multiple divs ine one step in intro.js from version 2.9.0.
However, I have 3 seperate divs that are together, how do I use document.querySelectorAll() to select them? I've tried something like:

```
element: document.querySelectorAll(div1, div2, div3)
```

which should work theoretically work, but doesn't

Answer (score -1):

```
{
       element: document.querySelectorAll('div1')[0],
        onboard: 'Hi i am dashboard tour .',
        position: 'right',
        highlightClass: 'transon-fix'
      },
{
        element: document.querySelectorAll('div2')[1],
        onboard: 'Hi i am dashboard tour .',
        position: 'right',
        highlightClass: 'transon-fix'
      },
{
        element: document.querySelectorAll('div3')[2],
        onboard: 'Hi i am dashboard tour.',
      },
```